# Unity3d project does not display images on samsung galaxy tablets

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, samsung-mobile

I have created a 2D game in Unity and have successfully created it PC build now I want to port it on Android devices. I have created the android build and It works on most of my android devices except on Samsung Galaxy tablets. On Samsung Galaxy tablet devices, it does not display the main menu backgrounds.
I have checked dimensions of the image these are 2048 X 2048.
In the inspector of unity the properties of image are asss follows:
type is sprite, max size is 1024 and compressed 
 On other android devices,(google nexus, micromax phones, bluestacks) it displays the images properly. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Did you try to change texture compression in build settings? BTW does it show any images?

Comment: yes it shows all the images except the main menu background. the texture settings are: type is sprite max size 1024 and compressed

Comment: Compression nothing to do then.

Comment: what should I do? I want to display the image

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the actual image to 512x512 for testing purposes? So we know if texture size is the problem. Also check the importer settings for the various devices. Perhaps it's set to 1024 in the "default" but to other resolution in the Android specific settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found out what I was doing wrong.
the textures were not appropriate according to the resolution of the screen. After I created another set of textures and setting the compression and max size to 2048 X 2048 it started displaying.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to set you image as "Sprite" from Inspector.